# Solving Some Transcendental Equations

Tags: special-functions, elementary-functions

How do you solve for $a$ in each of the equations $$a^{a^a}=b^c$$ $$a^{a^{a^a}}=b^c$$ $$a^{a^{a^a}}=b^{c^d}?$$

Comment: Well a must be 1, right?

Comment: It may not be a system of equations, but three equations to be solved separately?

Comment: @John Yes. Three different a values.

Answer (score 2):

Since *b*, *c*, *d* are independent of *a*, the right hand term can be replaced with a single symbol which represents a constant. Let this symbol be *A*. We have $a^{a^a}=A\iff a^a\ln a=\ln A\iff a\ln a$ $+\ln\ln a=\ln\ln A$. By letting $a=e^t$, we have $t\cdot e^t+\ln t=\ln\ln A$, which obviously isn't even expressible in terms of the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), since it can only solve equations of the form $t\cdot e^t$ = constant, but, in this case, $\ln\ln A-\ln t\neq$ constant, since it depends on *t*. Which of course does not mean that names or notations for *a* do not exist, or that its value cannot be found by numerical methods: they are called [super-roots or super-radicals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Inverse_relations), but they possess an analytical solution only for the case $n=1$ or [$n=2,$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Example_2) where *n* represents the height of the power-tower of *a*'s. This operation of repeated exponentiation is called **tetration**, by the way.