# basic maths about the solution of a question

Tags: calculus

homework exercise:

find $x$ given that $ a $ and $ b $ are constants.
Here is the equation that needs to be solved.

$$ x^{x^x} = a + b $$

i have no idea  how to solve this problem. please help me

my idea was to plot this equation to get some visualization?

are there many solutions maybe?

Comment: Are you sure about this equation? It cannot be solved using elementary functions.

Comment: i dont understand you mean antonio can you explain please?

Comment: @DonAntonio: I think the objective is to find $x$, provided $a$ and $b$. For instance, if $a = 1$ and $b = 0$, there is a solution in $x = 1$; and if $b = -2$ instead, there is a solution in $x = -1$. But why there are two parameters $a$ and $b$ I could not say --- the problem only depends on their sum.

Comment: You're right, @NieldeBeaudrap, but then again what you meantion: why two constants?

Comment: See my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580994/solving-some-transcendental-equations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, notice that a + b = c. So you want to solve x^x^x = c. The good idea ius effectively to plot the function first in order to have a rough idea of where is the solution. When this is done, just use Newton method. Suppose that c=10^4; a plot will show you that the solution is between 2.8 and 3.0.
Starting with a guess (name it x_old), the Newton iterates are computed as
x_new = x_old - f[x_old] / f'[x_old]
Let me be lazzy and select x_old = 2.8. Then, starting from there, the Newton iterates will successively be 3.04760, 2.97849, 2.93880, 2.92855, 2.92800.
You can continue the iterations until you reach the desired accuracy.

Comment: Note that there is an ambiguity for `x^x^x`. It seems that you solved $(x^x)^x=10^4$, for $x^{x^x}=10^4$ the solution would be $\approx 2.507234$.

Comment: @gammatester. You are perfectly correct !